# QGIS 3 on Mac, Can't run semi-automatic classification system plug-in

Tags: qgis-plugins, mac, qgis-3

I am trying to use QGIS 3 as it has a feature the previous version does not have, and have run into an issue when trying to run the semi-automatic classification system plug-in. Instead of opening up the plug-in, it displays the following error log. Has anyone had this issue before or have any idea how to resolve this issue?

```
Couldn't load plugin 'SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor: 'dev/fd/18' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1353, in 
    fontManager = json_load(_fmcache)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 888, in json_load
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/samuelkozlowski/.matplotlib/fontlist-v300.json'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 337, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/Users/samuelkozlowski/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/__init__.py", line 65, in classFactory
    from .semiautomaticclassificationplugin import SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/samuelkozlowski/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/semiautomaticclassificationplugin.py", line 74, in 
    from .ui.semiautomaticclassificationplugindialog import SemiAutomaticClassificationPluginDialog
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/samuelkozlowski/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/ui/semiautomaticclassificationplugindialog.py", line 39, in 
    from .ui_semiautomaticclassificationplugin_scatter_plot import Ui_ScatterPlot
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/samuelkozlowski/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/ui/ui_semiautomaticclassificationplugin_scatter_plot.py", line 453, in 
    from .scatterwidget2 import ScatterWidget2
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/samuelkozlowski/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/ui/scatterwidget2.py", line 44, in 
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigCanvas
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 9, in 
    from matplotlib.backend_bases import _Backend
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 46, in 
    from matplotlib import (
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 8, in 
    from matplotlib import cbook, dviread, font_manager, rcParams
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1363, in 
    _rebuild()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1344, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 978, in __init__
    ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 270, in findSystemFonts
    fontfiles.update(OSXInstalledFonts(fontext=fontext))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 218, in OSXInstalledFonts
    for directory in directories
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 220, in 
    for path in list_fonts(directory, ext)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 157, in list_fonts
    for path in filter(Path.is_file, Path(directory).glob("**/*.*"))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 156, in 
    return [str(path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 1100, in glob
    for p in selector.select_from(self):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 559, in _select_from
    for starting_point in self._iterate_directories(parent_path, is_dir, scandir):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 549, in _iterate_directories
    for p in self._iterate_directories(path, is_dir, scandir):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 549, in _iterate_directories
    for p in self._iterate_directories(path, is_dir, scandir):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 547, in _iterate_directories
    if entry.is_dir() and not entry.is_symlink():
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor: 'dev/fd/18'
```